# Context menu in firefox contains all possible items and is too large

Tags: firefox, context-menu

Seems my browsers context menu went broken - it now contains all thinkable options ("play", "add to dictionary", "fullscreen", "save image as") and the menu items do not alter when different HTML elements are clicked.
How do I fix this bug? It also seems that firefox developpers do not think anyone will ever need to alter my language localisations, so the screenshot is in czech.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Some general techniques for debugging firefox bugs that might help narrow down the problem: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-and-diagnose-firefox-problems

Comment: Mine began to do this as well, as soon as I updated to Firefox 20.

Comment: I reinstaled the program. Helped. I hope it won't do it again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Firebug causing the problem. Update it to 1.11.2 (using right-clic -> Find Updates) and the problem goes away (Source: [mozillazine](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=2689373) and myself)

Answer (score 0):

1. As an alternative please look at this extension called [menu editor](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/menu-editor/?src=search).
2. Before trying the first option try to identify the extension which is showing the menu, go to that extension's options and much likely it will have checkbox to disable the context menu option.